# PHP Error message Upload images to remote server

Tags: plugins, php, errors

I'm trying to fix an old plugin that is giving me a php error. I've work with website developer for years but my knowledge of php is limited. If anyone can get me advice I would appreciate it.

The orginal plugin is [Upload images to remote server](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74180/upload-images-to-remote-server)

Usage: Lets you use an FTP-Server as media-server in WordPress.

When I check the php code at https://rextester.com/l/php_online_compiler I get error message

> Error(s), warning(s):
>   PHP Fatal error:
>   Uncaught Error: Call to
>   undefined function `add_filter()` in 2062826375/source.php:34
>   Stack
>   trace: #0 {main} thrown in 2062826375/source.php on line 34

Line 34 is `add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload', 'get_file_name' );`

Any thoughts on how to fix this? 
Thank you
Kimberly

Comment: [`add_filter()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) is a WordPress function, not a native PHP function, which is why your online PHP tester doesn't know about it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've out of my depth on this.